# How to get name and size of file using JS and input[type="file"]

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

There is the following code:

```
  element.bind 'change', (changeEvent) ->
    reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = (loadEvent) ->
      attachments.push loadEvent.target.result
    console.log(changeEvent)
    reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0])
```

As you can see I can get a file content ("data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJeTw7fgKNCAwIG9iago8PAovQ29sb3JTcGFj ..."), but I need to get these params:

- Filename
- Size
- Content-Type (image or not)

How can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`changeEvent.target.files` is a array of objects describes a uploaded file.

```
file = changeEvent.target.files[0]

if 'name' in file
    console.log "name: #{file.name}"
else
    console.log "name: #{file.fileName}"

if 'size' in file
    console.log "size: #{file.size} bytes"
else
    console.log "size: #{file.fileSize} bytes"

if 'mediaType' in file
    console.log "type: #{file.mediaType}"
```